# function name not storing return value in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm in my 3rd week of a required college programming course. I was given an assignment to calculate BMI. I can write code that produces the desired output, but the instruction say I must use functions and that is giving me trouble. Here is the code I have come up with and I believe that maybe my issue is that on lines 12, 16, and 20, the input value is not being stored in the function name. Also something else seems to be wrong because when I run it, it asks for the student height twice. If someone could look at this and give me some direction I would really appreciate it.

Instructions...

You are the nutritional coach for a local high school football team. You realize that some of the players are not up to par having returned from summer break. Realizing nutrition plays a key in a productive team, you decide to implement a Body Mass Index Program.
Write a modularized Body Mass Index (BMI) Program which will calculate the BMI of a team player. The formula to calculate the BMI is as follows:
BMI = Weight *703 / Height^2
Note: Height^2 means, the value of Height raised to the power of 2.
Your program should utilize the following functions:
A method to obtain the weight of a player
A method to obtain the height of a player
A method to calculate the BMI of a player
A method to display the height, weight, and calculated BMI

```
import math
import sys
print("King's BMI Calculator")

while True:
    name = input("Please enter student's name or press 0 to quit:")
    if name == "0":
        break

    def h():
        height = int(input("Please enter student's height in inches:"))
        return height

    def w():
        weight = int(input("Please enter student's weight in pounds:"))
        return weight

    def bmi():
        total = float((str(w() * 703)/str(h() * str(h()))))
        return total

    def printbmi():
        print(name + "'s BMI Profile")
        print("Height:", str(h(), "inches"))
        print("Weight:", str(w(), "lbs"))
        print("BMI Index:" + str(float(round(bmi(), 1))))
        return

    def main():
        h()
        w()
        printbmi()

    main()
```

Comment: What does "the input value is not being stored in the function name" mean? And it asks for height twice since you call `h` twice.

Comment: http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#variable-scope-and-lifetime

Comment: This is not a tutorial service. You need to ask a *specific question*. But here's a something that you should consider - why are you *defining* your functions withint the while-loop? Define them outside and call them inside. Also, you are getting prompted for input twice because *that is exactly what you've coded*. You call `h` and `w` in `main`, and again in `printbmi` which itself is called from `main`. At no point are you saving any of the returned values, so it seems kind of pointless. Just remove the calls to `h` and `w` in `main` and you'll be well on your way...

Comment: Also, you are calling `h` and `w` within `bmi`! You actually call `h` twice in `bmi`. Every time you call a function, the code inside the function runs. *Save the result of a single call to a variable*, and then pass that variable into your other functions...

Comment: I see what you mean about having called it twice. I will work on it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call a function (i.e. `function_name()`), the function is executed. Therefore, your script will ask for input *whenever* `w()` or `h()` is called. A simple solution would be to store the return value to a variable, maybe to `weight = w()` and `height = h()` so that you can use the variables when needed instead of calling the entire function every time.

```
def w():
    # ...
    return weight

def h():
    # ...
    return height

def bmi(w, h)
    # ...
    return total

def printbmi(w, h, total):
    # print(w, h, total)

def main():
    # prompt
    weight = w()
    height = h()
    total = bmi(weight, height)
    printbmi(weight, height, total)

while True:
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code by considering the followings.

- Define the functions (`h(),w(),bmi()`) outside the `while` loop.
- Don't call `h()` and `w()` inside `main()` because you are calling them inside `printbmi()`. So, your program will ask for input twice for each student.
- You should move the `main()` function outside the loop as well.

You have problem in your `printbmi()` and bmi() functions as well. You are calling the `h()` and `w()` functions many times.

You can update your code as follows.

```
import math
import sys

def h():
    height = int(input("Please enter student's height in inches: "))
    return height

def w():
    weight = int(input("Please enter student's weight in pounds: "))
    return weight

def bmi(height, weight):
    total = float((weight * 703)/(height * height))
    return total

def printbmi(name):
    print(name + "'s BMI Profile")
    height = h()
    print("Height:", str(height), "inches")
    weight = w()
    print("Weight:", str(weight), "lbs")
    print("BMI Index:" + str(float(round(bmi(height, weight), 1))))

def main(name):
    printbmi(name)


print("King's BMI Calculator")
while True:
    name = input("Please enter student's name or press 0 to quit:")
    if name == "0":
        break
    else:
        main(name)
```

It outputs:

```
King's BMI Calculator
Please enter student's name or press 0 to quit:Jack
Jack's BMI Profile
Please enter student's height in inches: 12
Height: 12 inches
Please enter student's weight in pounds: 16
Weight: 16 lbs
BMI Index:78.1
Please enter student's name or press 0 to quit:0
```